# popup on click not open Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I face a situation where google chrome returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', '.show_popup', function(){
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');    
    callAjax($(this).attr('href'), 'mode=ajax', function(t){
        $('.popup-screen').html(t);
        $('.main-overlay').show();

        // $('').raty();
        $('#star').raty({
          click: function(score, evt) {
            $('#review_rating').val( score);
          }
        });
        // window.scroll(0,0);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".screenTable").offset().top },500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please help and also after error at

> XMLHttpRequest.self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange

Comment: What about the `.screenTable` element(s)? Can you ensure that at least one matching element exists on your HTML when this code is run?

Comment: Go into the debugger and find out what the value of `$(".screenTable").offset()` is

Comment: I think jQuery not get the element. add your html code.

Comment: please add your html code,so that people can check

Answer (score 2):

This error is showing up because element with class `.screenTable` could not be found.

You can check the existence of element before calling `top` to prevent error

```
    var STable = $('.screenTable');
    if (STable.length) //1
    { 
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".screenTable").offset().top },500);
      alert("top");
    }
    else{
    alert("element not found, so no top");
    }
```

Always wrap your function under `$( document ).ready()` [More info on document.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

//All elements has been loaded and are available.

});
```